# how to define write-byte for 1 in XSLT-1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to include in my xslt for write byte 1 and write bye 3

as similarly we are doing for CR, LF, AMP ...like how can we write integer 1 in hexadecimal
it was not allowing me to do.

is allowing to do CR but it was not working &#0D; in xslt 
similarly i have tried for to implement SOH as  it was not working can any please ..help on this

i have tried a lot for to implement below task, can any suggest me it was helpful for me

```
Mnemonic    Hex value        Unicode       Description
<SOH>        X’01’           <U+0001>    Start of Heading message
<ETX>        X’03’           <U+0003>     End of Text message


U+     0    1   2   3
0000  NUL SOH STX ETX
0010  DLE DC1 DC2 DC3
0020  sp   !   "   #
0030   0    1  2   3
```

i am trying to implement SOH and ETX, you related code check you see above attached screen shot.

Comment: can any one suggest some thing on this ?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev how can i solve this above issue in xslt-1.0

Answer (score 0):

I guess this cannot be done; see extract from w3.org below: certain characters are not allowed.

Character Range
[2]    Char    ::=    #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]  /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */

Also see [Things XSLT can't do](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nono.html#d1874e918) - an oldie but probably still valid.

Comment: Note: this is from XML version 1.0 documentation on [w3.org/TR/REC-xml](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)

Comment: XML version 1.1 seems to be broader, although using the additional control characters is discouraged; see [w3.org/TR/xml11](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/)

Comment: thank u for replying, i have edited my question more briefly,for to usage of SOH and ETX in xslt-1.0 and i have provided unicode also for that in the above question

Comment: XSLT 1.1 has been dropped and never really got implemented. XSLT 2.0 may provide more help but I'm not sure.

Comment: @samjudson afaik the XSLT version is not relevant here; it's the XML version. Not sure whether all tools and browsers support XML 1.1 though.

Comment: Probably, just wanted to highlight that no-one should be using XSLT 1.1 as it isn't supported anywhere.